# Multi modal graphe algorithm

Tags: neo4j, routes, spring-data-neo4j

I am creating an application that finds all possible routes a user can take to get from point A to point B using different or specified public transportation modes (e.g. trains, buses, tram, etc). Of course walking edges are permitted. I am using neo4j to store Data, please can you suggest me an algorithm to find the shortest path, i have never worked with multi modal graphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher (the Neo4j query language) has a function called [`shortestPath`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/) and `allShortestPaths` that can be used for finding the shortest path that matches a given pattern.

Check out the documentation [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html#query-shortest-path). For example:

```
MATCH (martin:Person { name:"Martin Sheen" }),(oliver:Person { name:"Oliver Stone" }),
  p = shortestPath((martin)-[*..15]-(oliver))
RETURN p
```

With routing, you often want to take into account the cost, often represented by a property on the relationship. There are several path finding graph algorithms that can be used with Neo4j that will take cost into account. Specifically, the [Dijkstra algorithm](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-and-get-a-single-path) is exposed via the Neo4j REST API. More graph algorithms are available with the Java API, as described [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo.html).